# Dash - Include custom html object

Tags: python, html, iframe, plotly-dash

I'm creating a Dash application in Python to showcase results of some Topic Analysis I performed. For topic analysis there is a nice visualisation tool called pyLDAvis. I used this tool, and saved its output as a html file named `lda.html`:

```
# Visualisatie
topic_data =  pyLDAvis.gensim.prepare(ldamodel, doc_term_matrix, dictionary, mds = "mmds")#mds = 'pcoa')
pyLDAvis.save_html(topic_data, 'lda.html')
pyLDAvis.display(topic_data)
```

My current Dash application includes a table that can be filtered on multiple topics. Underneath this table I want to present `lda.html`. The below code contains some of the attempts I have done

```
#import os

#STATIC_PATH = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath('lda.html')), 'static')
#STATIC_PATH
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
import dash_dangerously_set_inner_html
from dash import dash_table
from dash.dependencies import Input
from dash.dependencies import Output

app = dash.Dash()

topics = df_topics_wegschrijven['Topic'].unique().tolist()
                                  
app.layout = html.Div(
    children=[
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id="filter_dropdown",
            options=[{"label": tp, "value": tp} for tp in topics],
            placeholder="Selecteer een topic",
            multi=True,
            value=df_topics_wegschrijven.Topic.unique(),
        ),
        dash_table.DataTable(id = "table-container", 
                             data = df_topics_wegschrijven.to_dict('records'), 
                             columns =  [{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df_topics_wegschrijven.columns],
                            ),
        #html.Iframe(src='/static/lda.hmtl'), #style=dict(position="absolute", left="0", top="0", width="100%", height="100%"))
        html.Iframe(src=r"C:\Users\MyUserName\Documents\lda.html")
        #html.Iframe(topic_data)
    ]
)  

@app.callback(
    Output("table-container", "data"), 
    Input("filter_dropdown", "value")
)
def display_table(topic):
    dff = df[df_topics_wegschrijven.Topic.isin(topic)]
    return dff.to_dict("records")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False)
```

This code outputs the following:
[image]

As you can see there is an empty white square, where I would expect my  `lda.hmtl`  to be. For the code I commented out, the results are:

1. html.Iframe(src='/static/lda.hmtl') -> The white square is now filled with 'Not Found
   The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.'
2. html.Iframe(topic_data) -> the entire dash application turns into 'Error loading layout'.

To me it seems like what I did in my uncommented code should be correct (i.e. there is no error feedback except the square being blank), but I don't understand why it returns a blank square.

When I for instance try

```
import webbrowser
  
webbrowser.open_new_tab('lda.html')
```

The visualisation loads as intended. I just cannot get it to work within my Dash application.

Does anyone have suggestions on how I can resolve my problem and load the pyLDAvis html file into Dash correctly?

Comment: Hello, have you found a way to display your LDA model in dash app please ? Thank you !

Comment: Hey, what you need to do is put ‘lda.html’ in a folder called ‘assets’. Then html.Iframe(src='assets/lda.html')
should do what you need. If it doesn’t work let me know and I can share my code with you.

Comment: Hello again, indeed it works now, thank you so much ! @Coinman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've written the file extension as `.hmtl` instead of `.html`. That is probably the cause of the first problem.

**UPDATE**

I noticed that you've put `lda.html` into the `static` folder. In Dash,  `assets` folder is used to store external resources.

```
html.Iframe(src='assets/lda.html')
```

Or in a more pythonic way

```
html.Iframe(src=app.get_asset_url('lda.html'))
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately it did not resolve my error, I still get the same error as before.

Comment: You've also used `src='/static/lda.hmtl'` which made the path absolute because of the initial `/` instead of `src='static/lda.hmtl'`.